# How can I determine how much memory my program is currently occupying

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

> **Related to my previous question:**
>   **[Preventing Memory issues when handling large amounts of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427410/preventing-memory-issues-when-handling-large-amounts-of-text)**

Is there a way to determine how much memory space my program is occupying?  I end up processing a large amount of text file and usually store the processed objects in memory.  There are times where there will be too much information, and I will run out of memory.  I have a solution for avoiding the memory allocation problem, but I only want to use it when necessary, to avoid paging, which will ultimately decrease my performance when it's not necessary.  Is there a way to figure out how much memory I am occupying, so that I can page my information only when necessary?

**NOTE:** I am looking for a solution that my program can utilize to begin paging when necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [`GC.GetTotalMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory.aspx):

> Retrieves the number of bytes
>   currently thought to be allocated. A
>   parameter indicates whether this
>   method can wait a short interval
>   before returning, to allow the system
>   to collect garbage and finalize
>   objects.

The important thing to note is this part: "Retrieves the number of bytes *currently thought to be allocated"*.   This means that this method may not be 100% accurate - as long as you know this going in, you should be able to get a rough idea of your virtual memory utilization at a given point in your application execution.

**Edit:** Let me now offer a different solution that will probably be more productive: use [`perfmon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645516%28VS.71%29.aspx) and the [CLR performance counters](http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/06/30/perfmon-your-debugging-buddy/).

Comment: >"[...] best available approximation of the number of bytes currently allocated in managed memory" Wont this get the amount of memory used by all managed assemblies?

Comment: Yes it will but only in the current AppDomain.  I strongly recommend using perfmon for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 8):

```
long bytes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64;
```

Answer (score 3):

You really need to use a code Profiler. These will tell you exactly what's happening, where the memory is being used up, etc.

FYI: It's rarely where you think it is.

Comment: +1: though it doesn't quite satisfy your question (since you want to do it in code), this is still true; profiling should still be one step of your design because it will illuminate aspects of memory usage that might be obscured by code-accessible measurements. For example, `WorkingSet64` includes shared memory, which you may want to subtract from the total when deciding whether to page or not.

Answer (score 3):

long bytes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 for more [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64.aspx)