# Measure RAM + CPU usage of .Net objects

Tags: c#, .net, object, cpu, ram

I've been wondering if it's possible to measure the amount of RAM and CPU consumption of various .NET objects.

These could be a function, a method or even a class. The "greater" the better.

I've tried searching a bit for some information regarding this subject, but I've come out empty-handed.

Any information would be appreciated.

Just for your information, I know how to measure the RAM and CPU consumption of an application or process, and that isn't the answer I'm looking for.

EDIT:
First of thanks for your fast response.

The solution I'm looking for needs to be code-based, since it's to be applied in a existing application. Sorry for the misguidance.

Comment: Possible duplicate with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440720/how-can-i-determine-how-much-memory-my-program-is-currently-occupying

Comment: Well, you are aware that there is a whole profiling API, right? What about you head over to the documentation ;)

Comment: I disagree with the suggested duplicate(which is for whole process) and off topic close votes. OP never asked a tool.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Agree with you. I was obscured by the way OP has written the question.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: He also never asked "for code" so the much more likely thing is, that he is searching for a tool.

Comment: @chrfin: Well, that makes it off-topic for SO...

Comment: @chrfin Unless he asked for tool explicitly we can't assume he is asking for tool.

Comment: IMO: Its "unclear what he is asking" => @OP: Can you specifiy if you want a tool or a "code-solution"? I guessed he wants a tool, as I sadly see it regularly how many (full-time) developers do not know what a profiler is or that they "even exist"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are searching for a profiler. There are many out there. [dotTrace](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/&ei=2y6DU5nZAqHf4QS8uoGIDQ&usg=AFQjCNGbmcIU7aPIZYLu465RUUms0Xaw6Q&sig2=gPgZzmHcNh3NCV6Un87AZA&bvm=bv.67720277,d.bGE), [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/), [ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/), ...

Comment: Alternativels he is searching for the profiler API - that is in the documentation ;)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: He never said that. He said he wants to measure code, not that he wants to do it "via code"...

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. Thought OP was referring to 'classes, functions' as being the code solution, but I think it is about the measurement now. My bad.